# what is the best and valid way for cross browser min-height?

Tags: css, xhtml

for `#main-content`

I don't want to give any fix height because content can be long and short but if content is short then it should take minimum height `500px`.

i need compatibility in all browser.

Is thery any w3c valid and cross browser way without using !important because i read !important should not be used

> In conclusion, don’t use the
>   !important declaration unless you’ve
>   tried everything else first, and keep
>   in mind any drawbacks. If you do use
>   it, it would probably make sense, if
>   possible, to put a comment in your CSS
>   next to any styles that are being
>   overridden, to ensure better code
>   maintainability.
>
> I tried to cover everything
>   significant in relation to use of the
>   !important declaration, so please
>   offer comments if you think there’s
>   anything I’ve missed, or if I’ve
>   misstated anything, and I’ll be happy
>   to make any needed corrections.

http://www.impressivewebs.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-important-css-declaration/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

min-height is supported in every major browser except IE6 (see [QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#link3)).

In IE6, an element will expand to contain its content, even if it has a fixed height; height in IE6 is in effect min-height.

So a cross-browser min-height declaration would be:

```
#main-content {
    min-height: 500px;
}
* html #main-content { /* target IE6 */
    height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: (3 years later) it's worth mentioning that IE6 is almost dead and gone now (1% or less global usage?), for personal sites I do not consider it in my code, for clients I tend to sway them away from bothering too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one:

```
#main-content {  
    min-height:500px;  
    height:auto !important;  
    height:500px;  
}
```

Also see this for IE:

**[Cross Browser CSS Min-Height](http://davidwalsh.name/cross-browser-css-min-height)**

Comment: but i dont want to set fix height for IE.

Comment: there is no other solution then this one if you don't want to use JS or other CSS Hacks. They say to not use !important if you tried anything else, i tried anything else believe me

Answer (score 0):

min-height: 100px; /* sets min-height value for all standards-compliant browsers */

min-height doesn't work for IE hence you can use:-

height: expression( this.scrollHeight < 100 ? "100px" : "auto"); /* sets min-height for IE */

Comment: css expression is also not advisable to use.

Comment: this I think will help you to specify min-height without giving fix width and should sole your problem. Not sure though how it can be done without using expression