# fixed background in IE -any resolution

Tags: css

In my website, I have to use the background image that is fixed in any resolution, and should not change when control+scroll. I have used the following css.

```
/* CSS style */
img.bg {
   /* Set rules to fill background */
   min-height: 100%;
   min-width: 1024px;

   /* Set up proportionate scaling */
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;

   /* Set up positioning */
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
   img.bg {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -512px; }
  }
```

This code working fine in Firefox, but background image is shrinking in **IE7** browser. How to fix this issue.Anyone please help

Comment: Which IE version are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but your min-width and min-height may not be working for IE. have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688684/what-is-the-best-and-valid-way-for-cross-browser-min-height/2688766#2688766) for min-height fix.

Answer (score 0):

The IE7 behaves a little strange when it comes to min-width and min-height. In order to fix this you could try to set both, width and min-width to the same value for IE7.